# Linux utility for changing text in file

Tags: linux

I'm on linux Fedora having `a.dat` text file, which is a table of numbers. I have at columns 1 and 2 very big numbers, greater than `2000000`, all the other numbers are smaller than `1000`. I want to use linux utility which can open a file, search it for containing large numbers (condition is `>2000000`) and substitute each found number by the value of a counter which is incremented each time the number is substituted.

Is it possible todo in a terminal using maybe `grep` and how it can be done?

Comment: Learn about [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) and [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/)

Comment: Give two example lines of the file and sure enough somebody will post you an awk-one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using `awk`. Typically you can replace in a file using `sed`, but only replacing values bigger than 2000000 using `sed` will be tricky.

If I were you I would write a simple ruby or python script. In general it will take you less time and will be easier to maintain and read.